# Maxima not finding solution to simultaneous equations when one exists

Tags: systems-of-equations, maxima-software

I am using Maxima to solve the following equations simultaneously:
$$ 990=e^x \tag{1}$$
$$ 590=e^{(x - 10y)} \tag{2}$$
however the command 
`solve([990=%e^x, 590=%e^(x-10*y)], [x, y])` 
returns `[]` indicating Maxima couldn't find a solution.

For comparison, the command `solve([x^2+y^2=8, y=x], [x,y])` returns `[[x=2,y=2],[x=−2,y=−2]]`.

There is definitely a solution to the equations, so what could be stopping Maxima from finding it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have not specified that $x$ and $y$ are real valued.  There are many complex valued solutions to this system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
solve([exp(2*x)=10],[x]);
```

returns 2 answers

Rewriting your example:

```
solve([990=exp(x)],[x]);
solve([590=exp(x-10*y)],[y]), %;
```

returns 10 answers (only one real)